# can't able to get the text from the html table using robot framework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary, robotframework-swinglibrary, robotframwork-whitelibrary

Here is my code:

```
<div class="table row column" xpath="1">
    <div class="table__head">
      <div class="table__row">
        <div class="table__cell sys-log__col-wrapper sys-log__col-id">
          <div class="column small-2 sort_button_wrapper">
            <button class="sort-ascending" ng-click="sortBy('Id', false)"></button>
            <button class="sort-descending" ng-click="sortBy('Id', true)"></button>
          </div>
          ID
        </div>
        <div class="table__cell sys-log__col-wrapper sys-log__col-desc">Description</div>
      </div>
    </div>


${xpath_1} = //div[@class="table__row"]/div[1]
${xpath_2} = //div[@class="table__row"]/div[2]
```

I need to get ID as output for `xpath_1` and Description as output for `xpath_2`. but when I try to get output for below code I am getting:

```
${table_data}=  Get Table Cell  ${xpath_1}
```

The following error I am getting for this method

> Keyword 'SeleniumLibrary.Get Table Cell' expected 3 to 4 arguments, got 1.

(or)

```
${table_data}=  Get Text  ${xpath_1}
```

> empty space is coming as output for this method

Please suggest me how to get ID and Description as output from the above table using robot framework.

Comment: I'm not expecting `Get Table Cell` to work given that there is no `<table> </table>` involved in the html. Based on the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Table%20Cell) it also provided information on the other attributes it requires. Have you tried `Get Text` or `Get Value` to directly retrieve them?

Comment: I have tried with Get Text and it returns empty space and for Get Value i am getting None

Comment: Can you add the exact command you've tried to your question via the [edit] functionality? That way we have a better understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example as a basis I've been unable to replicate your problem because when using `Get Text` keyword actually provides the desired ID value. Below are the files and approach for replicating this in your own setup.

Create a new file:

**div_value.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="table row column" xpath="1">
    <div class="table__head">
      <div class="table__row">
        <div class="table__cell sys-log__col-wrapper sys-log__col-id">
          <div class="column small-2 sort_button_wrapper">
            <button class="sort-ascending" ng-click="sortBy('Id', false)"></button>
            <button class="sort-descending" ng-click="sortBy('Id', true)"></button>
          </div>
          ID774747474
        </div>
        <div class="table__cell sys-log__col-wrapper sys-log__col-desc">Description</div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

In the directory where this file goes execute the following command:

```
python -m http.server 8989
```

I use RED, but other IDE's or text editors will work too. Create a robot file

**div_value.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary    

*** Variables ***
${xpath_1}     //div[@class="table__row"]/div[1]
${xpath_2}     //div[@class="table__row"]/div[2]

*** Test Cases ***
Retrieve DIV Value
    
    Open Browser 
    ...    url=http://127.0.0.1:8989/div_value.html
    ...    browser=headlesschrome

    # ${table_data}=  Get Table Cell  ${xpath_1}
    ${table_data1} =  Get Text   ${xpath_1}
    ${table_data2} =  Get Value  ${xpath_1}
    No Operation
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

Using the debugger in RED I paused on the `No Operation` keyword line.

[image]